# idBag Generator Class Cast Exception

Tags: mysql, hibernate-mapping, hsqldb

I've been trying to get an idbag working in hibernate.  I been trying it against a MySql DB and a HSQLDB and I have also tried a couple different versions of Hibernate.  Hibernate 4 and Hibernate 3 are giving slightly different information as to the cause of the error but both say the same thing in the main: Class Cast Exception.

I hosted all my code on bitbucket in a public repo and everything is there to include the DDL for creating a MySql or HSQL DB with the relevant tables.  My HSQLDB version is 2.2.9 and the MySql version is 5.1.66 - My preference is to get it working on MySql.

Git Clone Command:
git clone https://pphi@bitbucket.org/pphi/idbag.git

Web Page:
https://pphi@bitbucket.org/pphi/idbag.git

When using Hibernate 4.0.1 I get this stack trace:

```
    Hibernate: insert into idBagTest.Team (nickname, mascot) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into idBagTest.Famous_Fan (first_name, last_name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into idBagTest.famous_fan_team (Team_id, team_fan_id, Famous_Fan_id ) values (?, ?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.LongTypeDescriptor.unwrap(LongTypeDescriptor.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeIdentifier(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:919)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1252)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1213)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at com.intertech.dao.TeamDaoHibernateImpl.saveTeam(TeamDaoHibernateImpl.java:19)
    at com.intertech.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

When using the Hibernate 3.1 I get this slightly different stack trace:

```
Hibernate: insert into Team (id, nickname, mascot) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Famous_Fan (id, first_name, last_name) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into famous_fan_team (Team_id, team_fan_id, Famous_Fan_id ) values (?, ?, ?)
5120 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.LongType - could not bind value 'POST_INSERT_INDICATOR' to parameter: 2; org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorFactory$2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorFactory$2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at org.hibernate.type.LongType.set(LongType.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeIdentifier(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1160)
    at org.hibernate.action.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at com.intertech.dao.TeamDaoHibernateImpl.saveTeam(TeamDaoHibernateImpl.java:19)
    at com.intertech.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-397

The use of identity for a generator class in the idBag is apparently not supported when using MySql and Hibernate.  Replaced the generator class with increment and got this:

Hibernate: insert into idBagTest.Team (nickname, mascot) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into idBagTest.Famous_Fan (first_name, last_name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select max(team_fan_id) from idBagTest.Famous_Fan_Team
Hibernate: insert into idBagTest.Famous_Fan_Team (Team_id, team_fan_id, Famous_Fan_id ) values (?, ?, ?)

The Repository has been updated with the working code.

Answer (score 0):

I have came across the same error,

After some research I came to conclusion that it is depends on two things.

1. What DB you are using plus
2. What @GenericGenerator - what strategy you are using.

I was able to resolved issue with following configuration.

1. DB - MySQL
2. Changed strategy to increment from native

My code looks like:
    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name="USERS_ADDRESSES", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID"))
    @GenericGenerator(name="hilogen",strategy="increment")
    @CollectionId(columns={@Column(name="ADDR_ID")},generator="hilogen",type=@Type(type="long"))
    private List addressList = new ArrayList();

Hope this help.

Thank,
Sagar Vyas